# HTML / CSS Page Layout - Expanding DIV

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple web page that has header, menu and content sections each are DIVs.

https://jsfiddle.net/wz8vctuq/1/

```
<body>
<div class="page">

    <div class="logo">
    </div>

<div class="wrap">

    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-inner">
        </div>       
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="menu left">
        </div>
        
        <div class="content-inner">
        
        <!-- content begins -->
        <div class="wrapper">
    
        </div>
            
        
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run this live I'm reading data from a MySQL database and then populating the content DIV.

The issue I have is the data overflows the bottom of the DIV, what I'd really like the content (white) DIV to grow to fill the data and I'd like the menu DIV (yellow) to expand so it is the same length as the content DIV.

Can anyone advise how I can do this. The fiddle shows what I have got so far.

Thanks

Comment: .wrapper { height: 100%; overflow: scroll; } will add scroll to container, or height should be set auto

Comment: @PaulineNemchak This doesn't expand the DIV, it limits the content within wrapper.
I'm trying to get the content DIV to expand and have the menu DIV match it's size.

Comment: then why did you set height? I think I can't catch you here

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question. It currently does not include any CSS, to match your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dfhxsnLc/1/

```css
.page {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 730px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.logo {
padding-bottom: 5px;
}


.wrap {
    width: 1022px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #ffffff;
    min-height: 660px;
}


/* Temp styles */
/*.header, .menu, .content, .footer { border: 1px solid black; }*/
.content, .menu, .footer { border-top: none; }

.menu.right { border-right: none; }
.menu.left { border-left: none; }

/* Core styles */
.header {
    position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffbfff;
}

.header-inner {
    line-height: 50px;  
    float:right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.content {
    position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 610px;
    display: table;
}
.content-inner {
    position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
    width: 886px;
    min-height: 590px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.frontpage {
    position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
    width: 886px;
    min-height: 610px;
}

.menu {
    position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
    width: 135px;
    border-top: none;
}

.menu.left { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
    height: 100%;   
    background: #ffffbf;
    display: table-cell;
}

.menu.left:after,
.menu.right:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu.right { float: right; }
.footer {
    position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}


.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    padding: 0px 15px 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page">

    <div class="logo">
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">

      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-inner">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="menu left"></div>
        <div class="content-inner">
          <!-- content begins -->
          <div class="wrapper">
            One advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old. Possible procured her trifling laughter thoughts property she met way. Companions shy had solicitude favourable own. Which could saw guest man now heard but. Lasted my coming uneasy marked so should. Gravity letters it amongst herself dearest an windows by. Wooded ladies she basket season age her uneasy saw. Discourse unwilling am no described dejection incommode no listening of. Before nature his parish boy.

            Folly words widow one downs few age every seven. If miss part by fact he park just shew. Discovered had get considered projection who favourable. Necessary up knowledge it tolerably. Unwilling departure education is be dashwoods or an. Use off agreeable law unwilling sir deficient curiosity instantly. Easy mind life fact with see has bore ten. Parish any chatty can elinor direct for former. Up as meant widow equal an share least.

            Another journey chamber way yet females man. Way extensive and dejection get delivered deficient sincerity gentleman age. Too end instrument possession contrasted motionless. Calling offence six joy feeling. Coming merits and was talent enough far. Sir joy northward sportsmen education. Discovery incommode earnestly no he commanded if. Put still any about manor heard.

            Village did removed enjoyed explain nor ham saw calling talking. Securing as informed declared or margaret. Joy horrible moreover man feelings own shy. Request norland neither mistake for yet. Between the for morning assured country believe. On even feet time have an no at. Relation so in confined smallest children unpacked delicate. Why sir end believe uncivil respect. Always get adieus nature day course for common. My little garret repair to desire he esteem.

            In it except to so temper mutual tastes mother. Interested cultivated its continuing now yet are. Out interested acceptance our partiality affronting unpleasant why add. Esteem garden men yet shy course. Consulted up my tolerably sometimes perpetual oh. Expression acceptance imprudence particular had eat unsatiable.

            Had denoting properly jointure you occasion directly raillery. In said to of poor full be post face snug. Introduced imprudence see say unpleasing devonshire acceptance son. Exeter longer wisdom gay nor design age. Am weather to entered norland no in showing service. Nor repeated speaking shy appetite. Excited it hastily an pasture it observe. Snug hand how dare here too.

            Improve ashamed married expense bed her comfort pursuit mrs. Four time took ye your as fail lady. Up greatest am exertion or marianne. Shy occasional terminated insensible and inhabiting gay. So know do fond to half on. Now who promise was justice new winding. In finished on he speaking suitable advanced if. Boy happiness sportsmen say prevailed offending concealed nor was provision. Provided so as doubtful on striking required. Waiting we to compass assured.

            You disposal strongly quitting his endeavor two settling him. Manners ham him hearted hundred expense. Get open game him what hour more part. Adapted as smiling of females oh me journey exposed concern. Met come add cold calm rose mile what. Tiled manor court at built by place fanny. Discretion at be an so decisively especially. Exeter itself object matter if on mr in.

            Effect if in up no depend seemed. Ecstatic elegance gay but disposed. We me rent been part what. An concluded sportsman offending so provision mr education. Bed uncommonly his discovered for estimating far. Equally he minutes my hastily. Up hung mr we give rest half. Painful so he an comfort is manners.

            Article nor prepare chicken you him now. Shy merits say advice ten before lovers innate add. She cordially behaviour can attempted estimable. Trees delay fancy noise manor do as an small. Felicity now law securing breeding likewise extended and. Roused either who favour why ham.

            One advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old. Possible procured her trifling laughter thoughts property she met way. Companions shy had solicitude favourable own. Which could saw guest man now heard but. Lasted my coming uneasy marked so should. Gravity letters it amongst herself dearest an windows by. Wooded ladies she basket season age her uneasy saw. Discourse unwilling am no described dejection incommode no listening of. Before nature his parish boy.

            Folly words widow one downs few age every seven. If miss part by fact he park just shew. Discovered had get considered projection who favourable. Necessary up knowledge it tolerably. Unwilling departure education is be dashwoods or an. Use off agreeable law unwilling sir deficient curiosity instantly. Easy mind life fact with see has bore ten. Parish any chatty can elinor direct for former. Up as meant widow equal an share least.

            Another journey chamber way yet females man. Way extensive and dejection get delivered deficient sincerity gentleman age. Too end instrument possession contrasted motionless. Calling offence six joy feeling. Coming merits and was talent enough far. Sir joy northward sportsmen education. Discovery incommode earnestly no he commanded if. Put still any about manor heard.

            Village did removed enjoyed explain nor ham saw calling talking. Securing as informed declared or margaret. Joy horrible moreover man feelings own shy. Request norland neither mistake for yet. Between the for morning assured country believe. On even feet time have an no at. Relation so in confined smallest children unpacked delicate. Why sir end believe uncivil respect. Always get adieus nature day course for common. My little garret repair to desire he esteem.

            In it except to so temper mutual tastes mother. Interested cultivated its continuing now yet are. Out interested acceptance our partiality affronting unpleasant why add. Esteem garden men yet shy course. Consulted up my tolerably sometimes perpetual oh. Expression acceptance imprudence particular had eat unsatiable.

            Had denoting properly jointure you occasion directly raillery. In said to of poor full be post face snug. Introduced imprudence see say unpleasing devonshire acceptance son. Exeter longer wisdom gay nor design age. Am weather to entered norland no in showing service. Nor repeated speaking shy appetite. Excited it hastily an pasture it observe. Snug hand how dare here too.

            Improve ashamed married expense bed her comfort pursuit mrs. Four time took ye your as fail lady. Up greatest am exertion or marianne. Shy occasional terminated insensible and inhabiting gay. So know do fond to half on. Now who promise was justice new winding. In finished on he speaking suitable advanced if. Boy happiness sportsmen say prevailed offending concealed nor was provision. Provided so as doubtful on striking required. Waiting we to compass assured.

            You disposal strongly quitting his endeavor two settling him. Manners ham him hearted hundred expense. Get open game him what hour more part. Adapted as smiling of females oh me journey exposed concern. Met come add cold calm rose mile what. Tiled manor court at built by place fanny. Discretion at be an so decisively especially. Exeter itself object matter if on mr in.

            Effect if in up no depend seemed. Ecstatic elegance gay but disposed. We me rent been part what. An concluded sportsman offending so provision mr education. Bed uncommonly his discovered for estimating far. Equally he minutes my hastily. Up hung mr we give rest half. Painful so he an comfort is manners.

            Article nor prepare chicken you him now. Shy merits say advice ten before lovers innate add. She cordially behaviour can attempted estimable. Trees delay fancy noise manor do as an small. Felicity now law securing breeding likewise extended and. Roused either who favour why ham.

            One advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old. Possible procured her trifling laughter thoughts property she met way. Companions shy had solicitude favourable own. Which could saw guest man now heard but. Lasted my coming uneasy marked so should. Gravity letters it amongst herself dearest an windows by. Wooded ladies she basket season age her uneasy saw. Discourse unwilling am no described dejection incommode no listening of. Before nature his parish boy.

            Folly words widow one downs few age every seven. If miss part by fact he park just shew. Discovered had get considered projection who favourable. Necessary up knowledge it tolerably. Unwilling departure education is be dashwoods or an. Use off agreeable law unwilling sir deficient curiosity instantly. Easy mind life fact with see has bore ten. Parish any chatty can elinor direct for former. Up as meant widow equal an share least.

            Another journey chamber way yet females man. Way extensive and dejection get delivered deficient sincerity gentleman age. Too end instrument possession contrasted motionless. Calling offence six joy feeling. Coming merits and was talent enough far. Sir joy northward sportsmen education. Discovery incommode earnestly no he commanded if. Put still any about manor heard.

            Village did removed enjoyed explain nor ham saw calling talking. Securing as informed declared or margaret. Joy horrible moreover man feelings own shy. Request norland neither mistake for yet. Between the for morning assured country believe. On even feet time have an no at. Relation so in confined smallest children unpacked delicate. Why sir end believe uncivil respect. Always get adieus nature day course for common. My little garret repair to desire he esteem.

            In it except to so temper mutual tastes mother. Interested cultivated its continuing now yet are. Out interested acceptance our partiality affronting unpleasant why add. Esteem garden men yet shy course. Consulted up my tolerably sometimes perpetual oh. Expression acceptance imprudence particular had eat unsatiable.

            Had denoting properly jointure you occasion directly raillery. In said to of poor full be post face snug. Introduced imprudence see say unpleasing devonshire acceptance son. Exeter longer wisdom gay nor design age. Am weather to entered norland no in showing service. Nor repeated speaking shy appetite. Excited it hastily an pasture it observe. Snug hand how dare here too.

            Improve ashamed married expense bed her comfort pursuit mrs. Four time took ye your as fail lady. Up greatest am exertion or marianne. Shy occasional terminated insensible and inhabiting gay. So know do fond to half on. Now who promise was justice new winding. In finished on he speaking suitable advanced if. Boy happiness sportsmen say prevailed offending concealed nor was provision. Provided so as doubtful on striking required. Waiting we to compass assured.

            You disposal strongly quitting his endeavor two settling him. Manners ham him hearted hundred expense. Get open game him what hour more part. Adapted as smiling of females oh me journey exposed concern. Met come add cold calm rose mile what. Tiled manor court at built by place fanny. Discretion at be an so decisively especially. Exeter itself object matter if on mr in.

            Effect if in up no depend seemed. Ecstatic elegance gay but disposed. We me rent been part what. An concluded sportsman offending so provision mr education. Bed uncommonly his discovered for estimating far. Equally he minutes my hastily. Up hung mr we give rest half. Painful so he an comfort is manners.

            Article nor prepare chicken you him now. Shy merits say advice ten before lovers innate add. She cordially behaviour can attempted estimable. Trees delay fancy noise manor do as an small. Felicity now law securing breeding likewise extended and. Roused either who favour why ham.



          </div>




        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Changes made:

1. `height` values should be `min-height`, so that the `div` elements can grow if the content becomes taller.
2. Use of `display: table;` on `.content` to treat its two child nodes (`.menu.left` and `.content-inner`) as columns with the same height. This solves the problem already, but if you prefer a newer solution, [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) could be used to achieve this instead.

Comment: thanks this does exactly what I was trying to do.  Do you have any suggestions or advise on how I can update the page to make it resize the layout based on resolution ?  Thanks

Comment: @Rocket https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media but it's a way more easy to work with flexbox or grid

Comment: @Rocket you're welcome, I'm glad it worked for you :) Sizing using proportional units (e.g. `%`) allows the layout to scale better across screen sizes. Beyond that, using `@media` also allows breakpoints in the layout not possible with flexbox or other CSS layouts alone, e.g. showing the sidebar only on screens larger than a certain size.

Answer (score 0):

[I've updated your Fiddle to reflect the changes you wanted](https://jsfiddle.net/osvbh2mw/)

Here's what your css file should look like:

```
   .page {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1024px;
        height: 730px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .logo {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    
    .wrap {
        width: 1022px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        background: #ffffff;
        height: 660px;
    }
    
    
    /* Temp styles */
    /*.header, .menu, .content, .footer { border: 1px solid black; }*/
    .content, .menu, .footer { border-top: none; }
    
    .menu.right { border-right: none; }
    .menu.left { border-left: none; }
    
    /* Core styles */
    .header {
        position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffbfff;
    }
    
    .header-inner {
        line-height: 50px;  
        float:right;
        padding-right: 50px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .content {
        position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        height: 610px;
        /* height: 100%; */
    }
    .content-inner {
        position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
     
        float: right;
      height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    }
    
    .frontpage {
        position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
        width: 886px;
        height: 610px;
        float: right;
    }
    
    .menu {
        position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
        width: 135px;
        height: 100%;
        border-top: none;
    }
    
    .menu.left { 
        float: left;
        height: 100%;   
        background: #ffffbf;
      width: 20%;
    }
    
    .menu.left:after,
    .menu.right:after {
        clear: both;
        content: "\0020";
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .menu.right { float: right; }
    .footer {
        position: relative; /* needed for stacking */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
    }
    
    
    .wrapper {
        overflow:scroll; 
        font-size: 14px; 
        padding: 0px 15px 10px 15px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: justify;
    }
```

I also justified your text so that it looks nicer within your div.

Comment: thanks for taking a look. This change adds multiple scroll bars, I'm trying to do this with out the scroll bars in the content DIV. What I'd like is to have the content and page DIV grow/expand vertically with the new content. This also needs to include the menu DIV.  Thanks

Comment: As a general rule - try to have all of your height/width attributes in percentages, not pixels. Pixels will automatically create issues with overflow and will inhibit the ability to grow or expand vertically. If you always have your height at a percentage of the screen, then no matter the amount of text you have, the div will grow with it. Also, there's no good way to implement this without using scroll - if you don't do it, then the browser will do it for you!